# Strange XPath behavior

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, selenium

Admittedly, I don't have much experience in selenium or advanced website building but this has had me stumped for a few days now

After trying to get selenium to find this one element 20 different ways, I ended up just using chromes console to try and find it through there with the $x() command. That's where I **really** got confused though, I have no idea why it's not finding it one second, then magically finding it the next

here's what the console output looks like:

[image: weird xpath behavior]

Strangely enough, even when I click on the element and retry the above xpath command, it **still** can't find it. The **only** way that i can get it to find the element is if I use chromes ctrl + shift + c command to click on the element and see it in element tab. I can't right click and inspect the element because it brings up it's own menu, it only works through that shortcut or clicking the button that activates that command.

I have a feeling this is why my Selenium script can't find the element and I'm not sure how to fix it or even **why** it's happening. Any input that could help wrap my head around this would be appreciated greatly, thank you!

Comment: can you please share your html?

Comment: You may be onto something...if i inspect element and copy part of that code and view the page source I can't find it in there. Maybe it has something to do with an iFrame? Does selenium work with iFrames do you know?

Comment: Yes.You need to switch to iframe first to access the elemet.

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't think of this before, thank you so much Kajal - really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

The element I wanted to click on was hidden under **THREE** iFrames which is why it couldn't find it. After switching through them, the script functioned correctly - Thank you to [Kajal Kundu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10885684/kajal-kundu) for his simple question of asking for the HTML, I don't know why I didn't think of iframes possibly messing it up until I started copying the code for him :)